# Word for leaving seat

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for someone jumping out of a sitting position, an alternative for saying "jolted out of their seats"?

Example sentence:

> The sudden interruption of his soothing music by the horrifying screech **jolted him from his seat**.

Comment: Uh, "stood up"?

Comment: @HotLicks Agreed. I don't think it can get any simpler

Comment: Please add more information to specify what kind of word you do want to use. Adding an example sentence would be a good way to do this. You can learn more about how to write one in the tag description for ["single word requests."](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Answer (score 2):

While there are several verbs for "left a sitting position" (such as "stood" or "arose"), I think the best one for what you describe is **sprung**.

> move or jump suddenly or rapidly upward or forward. *(Google)*

Answer (score 0):

"[***Jump to one's feet***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/jump-to-your-feet)" is a braodly used idiom and it means:

> to ***stand up very quickly***
>
> She jumped to her feet as the teacher walked into the room.

[Macmillan Online Dictionary]